# Flutter firebase check email exist inside firestore collection

Tags: firebase, flutter

I need to just check if user email exist in user collection or not. Right now I am doing like this

```
var check =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
 .where('email', isEqualTo: userData['email']).snapshots();
```

But when I print check its showing

```
Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
```

How can I check that email exist in that collection or not ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `check` variable is a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), while you seem to want it to be a boolean that indicates whether the query had any results.

To get that:

```
var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
 .where('email', isEqualTo: userData['email']).limit(1);
var snapshot = await query.snapshots();
var check = query.size > 0;
```

Note that I also added a `limit(1)` to the query, since you never need to read more than one document to determine if any matches exist.

Answer (score -1):

you can try or take reference form this method let me know if this solves your problem

```
 static Future<bool> emailCheck(String email) async {
  bool result = false;
   QuerySnapshot snapshot = await 
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get();
   snapshot.docs.forEach((f) {
    if (f['email'] ==email) {
      result =true;
    }
     });
 return result;
   }
```

Comment: I use this code like var check = emailCheck(userData['email']);
print(check); and add if else condition on check like if check is true or false but it's showing Instance of 'Future<bool>' on check not true or false can you please tell how to get that bool value. Thanks

Comment: look carefully here i am using a foreach loop to check if my email exits or not in the collection  if it does i am returning true oher wise false you can get the value like this..........      late bool chekuserexistsornot; chekuserexistsornot = await DataBaseServiceHelper. emailCheck(email);